# sed regex to replace multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, sed

The following sed expression is meant to operate on LaTeX source code and replace `citet` with `citep`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\\citet/\\citep/'
```

However, it seems that if `citet` appears twice in a row

```
\citet{bichot2011graph} \citet{DBLP:journals/corr/BulucMSSS13}
```

it replaces only the first occurrence and turns it into:

```
\citep{bichot2011graph} \citet{DBLP:journals/corr/BulucMSSS13}
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the global flag `g`:

```
sed -i -e 's/\\citet/\\citep/g'
```

See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) reference for more detail.

> g - Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the
>   first.